# PHPT avoid constructor and target functions directly

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpt

I have the following class:

```
class Validator {
 public function __construct($file){                
  $errors = $this->errors($file_array[CSV]['errors']);
  }
 public function errors_func($errors){
  if($errors != 0){
   throw new Exception('Error Uploading');
  }
 }
}
```

I'm attempting to target the `errors_func()` function directly through my test script without the need to first invoke the constructor. The PHPT test script can be seen below:

```
--TEST--
check_mime() function - A basic test to see if check mime works. :)
--FILE--

    <?php
    require_once('my/path');
    $valid = new Validation;
    $re = $valid->errors_func('1);
    var_dump($re);
    ?>
    --EXPECT--
    bool(true)
```

As you would expect though the test script fails becuase a parameter is expected when the object of the class is created. Is there a way to create an object of the Validation class without needing to pass an argument to the class __constructer?

Comment: Rewrite your class then

Comment: @u_mulder The example above is a very simplified version of the class, unfortunately I'm not in a position to refactor the class

Comment: Then you can't do anything.

Comment: @u_mulder Found a solution using ReflectionClasses wasn't something I was previously aware of

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to this by using [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php://). The new test script would look like this:

```
--TEST--
check_mime() function - A basic test to see if check mime works. :)
--FILE--

    <?php
    require_once('my/path');
    $valid = new ReflectionClass('Validator');
    $valid_direct = $valid->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
    $re = $valid_direct->errors_func('1);
    var_dump($re);
    ?>
    --EXPECT--
    bool(true)
```